# Android webview app - Wordpress site - token + user id

Tags: android, wordpress, webview, token

I have an android webview app. In the webview is a WordPress site.

Android app sent token information into my WordPress site (for sending push notifications). This works great. I have a list of tokens of app users.

BUT I need pair token with user id...

User in the android webview is signed into his account (in webview no in-app) - and this information is needed to get. Token I have, but I don't know user id.

There is code, for sending token information to my WordPress site:

```
private fun sendRegistrationToServer(token: String?) {
    val url = URL("https://example.com/push/savetoken/?device_token=" + token.toString() + "&device_type=android")
    val urlConnection: HttpURLConnection = url.openConnection() as HttpURLConnection
    try {
        val `in`: InputStream = BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream())
        readStream(`in`)
    } finally {
        urlConnection.disconnect()
    }
}
```

Question is how to get user id / how pair token with user id?

Cookie/localstorage/sessionstorage?

**UPDATE:** I writing user id into the cookie on website now.. This means that after login each user get into the cookies his wordpress user id.

It is possible: Android app gets this user id from cookie and use it in code for sending token? This means that user id will be added to the code for sending token - and I get token + user id to my wordpress databasse.

Please help.

Comment: add userId in save token request "&device_type=android" + "&id=" + {user_id}

if u have id, else save random android_id in sharedperefrences and use this saved android_id as user_id

Comment: My friend. Each user has user id from wordpress, however i don't have this user id. Please give me information how can i get user id  or maybe i should pair with user's token (which i already have thanks mobile webview app). 

Maybe browser in mobile app can save some cookie and mobile app can read this information where will be user id.?